# Why is my list comprehension function slower than my list appending function for string concatenation?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm working on a problem that takes in a string and outputs the compressed string with the outputs of repeated characters. For example: `aaabbcdddd` would return `a3b2c1b4`. It would also have to account for special cases like the same character occurring later in the string like `abcccccaaad` would need to return `a1b1c5a3d1` instead of `a4b1c5d1`. I have implemented two methods using list comprehension and building a list of strings then joining it.

Based on the info from: [Efficient String Concatenation](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/), my list comprehension function should be faster than building a list of strings and then joining it. Here are my two separate functions:

Using list comprehension:

```
counter = 1 # global count of repeating characters

def getCount(str1, char, ind):
    global counter
    returnStr = ''

    if char == str1[ind - 1]: # if current char is equal previous char, inc counter
        counter += 1
    else:        
        returnStr = f"{counter}{char}" # else return current count and new char
        counter = 1 # reset counter

    if ind == len(str1) - 1:
        returnStr += f"{counter}" # if at the end of str, append counter to returnStr

    return returnStr

def stringCompression(str1):
    # getCount() for indexes above 0 to be able to compare to previous characters
    newStr = ''.join([getCount(str1, char, ind) if ind > 0 else char for ind, char in enumerate(str1)])
    return newStr
```

Building list of strings then joining:

```
def stringCompression(str1):
    strArr = []
    counter = 0

    for char in str1:
        if not len(strArr):
            strArr.append(char)  # append first char to empty strArr
        elif char != strArr[-1]:
            # if char doesn't equal previous char, append counter and new char then reset counter
            strArr.append(str(counter))
            strArr.append(char)
            counter = 0
        counter += 1 # inc counter every pass

    strArr.append(str(counter)) # append final count of latest char
    return ''.join(strArr)
```

I am using this code to time each method:

```
start = time.time()
stringCompression('aabcccccaaaq'*100000)
end = time.time()
print("stringCompression = ", end - start)
```

And my list comprehension method is almost twice as slow as my other method. I am wondering why this is the case. Is it because I `enumerate` my list, which I need to do to keep track of my current index, or because my `getCount()` function is inefficient, or some other reason that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the list-comprehension, three if-conditions, one function call and `global`.
The second version only uses two if-conditions.

You can reduce to one if-condition inside the loop, to get even faster results:

```
def string_compression(string):
    string = iter(string)
    char = next(string)
    result = [char]
    counter = 1
    for new_char in string:
        if new_char != char:
            # if char doesn't equal previous char, append counter and new char then reset counter
            result.append(str(counter))
            result.append(new_char)
            counter = 0
            char = new_char
        counter += 1 # inc counter every pass
    result.append(str(counter)) # append final count of latest char
    return ''.join(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling a user-defined function and accessing a global variable are both relatively expensive. Your second version effectively inlines `getCount`, greatly reducing the overhead in breaking up the input string.